# Should I answer a bounty'd question if more information is required from the OP?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounties, expired-bounty

What should I do if I have commented on a bounty'd question asking for more information, the OP has not responded, and the bounty is about to run out?

I am specifically referring to [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39048673/github-pull-request-shows-too-many-changes-commits), but I am interested in the general case, so I haven't tagged this [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question).

<sub>Background for this specific question: The OP lists two problems in their question: GitHub shows too many commits to be merged, and the Merge button doesn't work. After some edits, it was clear why the extra commits show up (but not why the OP would expect otherwise, or why this hasn't happened before), but there was no indication of why the Merge button would not work. I commented asking for more information, and the OP has not yet responded.</sub>

All that to say: there is not enough information to provide a good answer to the question. There are 3 current answers, all of which say little more than "you should do a manual merge, and here's some debugging you can do".

I suspect that the ideal solution would have involved closing the question as lacking an MCVE until the OP has provided this information. However, given the [state of the SO Close Vote Queue](//stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats), it's not likely that it would have been closed before the bounty was added. (And since the bounty was added so quickly, I wouldn't have had the chance to ask for [help closing the question in chat](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).)

What should I do instead? Should I provide an incomplete answer (as other users have)? Does the fact that this question has a bounty (and the bounty is about to expire) change anything?

Comment: Don't under estimate what happens if you bring a question that needs to be closed [in front of the right eyes](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) ...

Comment: @rene Unless those eyes are moderators, there'll be no way for those users to close the question

Comment: @Servy yeah, we do have mods lurking though. Also, when noticed early enough these questions don't get a chance to be bountied ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a question doesn't provide enough information to answer it, it should be closed as "unclear what you're asking" (or as "lacking MCVE" on Stack Overflow, if appropriate). If such question currently has a bounty, you can't vote to close it, but you can flag it for moderator intervention and explain the situation. Also, in this specific case you can just wait these 3 hours until the bounty ends, and then vote to close it.

Comment: The fact that it's bountied means that it *can't* be closed, so it changes *something*.

Comment: Then say *that*, rather than saying that nothing is different as a result of the bounty, when something is different as a result of the bounty.